# First elisp attempt - minor mode for tab key not being invoked on tab?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've decided to get my toes wet with a bit of lisp, since I want to make emacs behave a little better when I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.  My command works fine.  It just performs `indent-for-tab-command` and if nothing happens, it performs `tab-to-tab-stop`, on the assumption that it's unlikely I was hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> just to have the point refuse to budge when I'm inside a multi-line string or some such.  After the first <kbd>TAB</kbd> press, it continues to do `tab-to-tab-stop` until either editing resumes, or the point is moved elsewhere.  AFAIK, my logic is ok, though my lisp code probably isn't!

Originally I just hacked this into my emacs dot files by doing `(local-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-dwim)` for major modes where I wanted this behaviour.  That worked as expected.

Then I decided that what I was doing was basically a minor mode, so I tried to move the key-binding into a minor-mode.  For some reason, even though the minor mode is enabled (as indicated in the mode line, and just from toggling it on and off), my `tab-dwim` function isn't being invoked when I hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.  I can still invoke it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> as expected.

What am I doing wrong with my minor mode's `:keymap`?

```
;;;
;; TAB DWIM

; buffer-local before/after point tracking
(setq point-before-tab nil)
(setq point-after-tab nil)
(make-local-variable 'point-before-tab)
(make-local-variable 'point-after-tab)

(defun tab-dwim ()
  "Indents normally once, then switches to tab-to-tab-stop if invoked again.

tab-dwim will always perform tab-to-tab-stop if the first TAB press does not
cause the point to move."

  (interactive)

  (print "in tab-dwim now") ; THIS LINE IS NEVER INVOKED ON TAB?

  (setq point-before-tab (point))

  (if (eq point-before-tab point-after-tab) ; pressed TAB again
      (tab-to-tab-stop)
    (indent-for-tab-command))

  (if (eq (point) point-before-tab) ; point didn't move
      (tab-to-tab-stop))
  (setq point-after-tab (point)))

(define-minor-mode tab-dwim-mode
  "Toggle tab-dwim-mode.
With a non-nil argument, turns on tab-dwim-mode. With a nil argument, turns it
off.

When tab-dwim-mode is enabled, pressing the TAB key once will behave as normal,
but pressing it subsequent times, will continue to indent, using
tab-to-tab-stop.

If tab-dwim determines that the first TAB key press resulted in no movement of
the point, it will indent according to tab-to-tab-stop instead."

  :init-value nil
  :lighter " DWIM"
  :keymap
  '(([TAB] . tab-dwim)))

(provide 'tab-dwim)
```

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are very close.

Try this for your keymap:

```
'(("\t" . tab-dwim)))
```

Comment: Woohoo! That simple :) On a side-note, the placement of my preparatory `setq` and `make-local-variable` calls feels a little incorrect. Should they be tucked inside the minor mode, or is it ok to configure them globally like that?

Comment: I would put the "make-local-variable" calls outside (because it is a global setting) and the "setq" calls inside.  I would also pick a prefix (like "dwim-tab") and name everything (functions and variables) with that prefix.  ELisp lacks namespaces, so prefixes are the usual convention.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use "\t" or the vector format "[(tab)]".

Some additional notes for your elisp development:

1. Avoid making global variables as much as possible.  In this case, I think dynamically binding with let is appropriate.  Also have a look at let*.
2. Understand the difference between `make-local-variable` and `make-variable-buffer-local`.  The way you've written your code, the buffer-local variable would only exist in the buffer that loads your package.
3. As Nemo mentioned, it's extemely extremely extremely recommended that you use a common prefix for all variables/functions related to each package.  Emacs has only one namespace, this is the "hacky" way to keep it somewhat organized.

Comment: Thanks, I've just re-namespaced everything and moved some stuff around. Just reading the manual for `let` now. Seems like a cleaner solution, I agree.

Comment: I didn't understand your logic there, let won't work in your current logic.  However, you don't need to track the point position at all.  You can just check the last-command variable to see if this is the second+ invocation.

Comment: That will work for multiple tab presses (which is 90% of what I'm trying to solve), but it won't help in the case where the first tab press didn't move the point (e.g. after hitting enter, then TAB inside a multi-line string). It does feel like there should be a cleaner way, I just don't think checking the last command is actually enough?

Comment: hmmm.  I had it right the first time, you can use let.  Post a question about how to move the variables in, and I'll post the code there.  Your original issue is resolved, so I don't want the code to be buried here.

Comment: Done, thanks, it's well-past my bedtime here in Melbourne, but I'm curious now :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586331/elisp-internal-variable-scoping-for-a-minor-mode-setq-make-local-varible-let

Comment: FWIW, `"\t"` and `[(tab)]` are _not_ the same thing. The first is the TAB character, which for a key binding means ASCII control character TAB, which is the same as `C-i`.  The second is function key `tab` -- it means whatever the `Tab` key of your keyboard sends.  If you want your code to handle both kinds of TAB key, then bind both of them.